# How to get dot class of list of Objects?

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

I want to serialize an List of Object with SimpleFramework xml.
I succeed with ordinary class but not with List of object.

I don't find the good syntax for do it with a List of object.

```
List< Shop > shop = new Persister().read(List<Shop>.class, data);
```

`List< Shop >.class` doesn't work

Thanks

Comment: `Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection< Shop >>() {
                    }.getType();`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it but it doesn't work.

Comment: This is due to type erasure. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do this directly; use [@ElementList](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/ElementList.html) instead.

Here's an example:

### Shop class

```
@Default // Or customize as you need
public class Shop
{
    private String name;

    public Shop(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private Shop() { /* Required default ctor */ }

    // ...
}
```

### ListExample

This is just a wrapper around the list.

```
@Root(name = "example")
public static class ListExample
{
    @ElementList(name = "Shops", inline = true)
    private List<Shop> shops;

    // ...
}
```

### Usage

```
String input = ... // Or what source you have
Serializer ser = new Persister();
ListExample readExample = ser.read(ListExample.class, input);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have already done that but i hoped that is an another way to do serialize with List < Shop >.